# ArangoDB Creating counter edge for every directed edge for bidirectional edges

Tags: graph-databases, arangodb, directed-graph

I am very new to graph database. And I have started with Arango. For this project I am not sure about the queries that I will encounter in future. I don't want to create bottlenecks. So I wanted to create undirected or bidirectional edges everywhere.

However as only directed edges are supported my current understanding is that if some vertex is not reachable by a `directed traversal` then I'll hit a bottleneck later. So whenever I am creating an edge `a -> b` I am also creating `b -> a` in the same edge collection.

Are my assumptions correct ? and Is the design decision acceptable ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While edges are always directed, you can choose to ignore the edge direction in a traversal by using `ANY`: https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/aql/graphs-traversals.html

- `OUTBOUND` to follow an edge in its defined direction (`_from` → `_to`)
- `INBOUND` to follow in the opposite direction (`_from` ← `_to`)
- `ANY` to follow regardless of the edge direction, inbound and outbound (`_from` ↔ `_to`)

[image: Traversal directions in graph]